# Ecilipse Static Project: Unable to Call/load CSS file from Xhtml

Tags: java, css, xhtml, concordion

I am new to concordion framework and for practice purpose I have created a ecilipse static project. I am successfully able to run Concordion sample program. however, I am not able to load/call CSS file from XHTML.
I am attached the screenshot for your reference.
Kindly help me in fixing the issue.
Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

it should work OK using a relative path - change the value of the href attribute to "../Adavnce_Concept1.css".

I don't know how to get it working using an absolute path.

Note that any custom stylesheet won't be copied to the Concordion output folder. You'll need to either copy it there yourself (for example in the build script), or [create an extension](http://concordion.org/Extensions.html#cssExample) to copy it.

Comment: :thank you for your respond. I have tried to change the value of href as you mentioned. Still It is not loading the CSS file:/.

Comment: Would you clarify whether the issue is before you run Concordion (eg. the CSS is not applied in Eclipse by opening the file with Web Browser or Web Page Editor), or after running Concordion (eg. opening the output file with a browser)? If it is the latter you will need to use the suggestions in the last paragraph of my answer.